# How to draw without replacement to fill in data set

Tags: random, stata

I am generating a data set where I first want to randomly draw a number for each observation from a discrete distribution, fill in `var1` with these numbers. Next, I want to draw another number from the distribution for each row, but the catch is that the number in `var1` for this observation is not eligible to be drawn anymore. I want to repeat this a relatively large number of times.

To hopefully make this make more sense, suppose that I start with:

```
id
1
2
3
...
999
1000
```

Suppose that the distribution I have is ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] that happen with probability [.2, .3, .1, .15, .25].

I would first like to randomly draw from this distribution to fill in `var`. Suppose that the result of this is:

```
id    var1
1     E
2     E
3     C
...   
999   B
1000  A
```

Now `E` is not eligible to be drawn for observations `1` and `2`. `C`, `B`, and `A` are ineligible for observations `3`, `999`, and `1000`, respectively.

After all the columns are filled in, we may end up with this:

```
id    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
1     E     C     B     A     D
2     E     A     B     D     C
3     C     B     A     E     D
...        
999   B     D     C     A     E
1000  A     E     B     C     D
```

I am not sure of how to approach this in Stata. But one way to fill in `var1` is to do something like:

```
gen random1 = runiform()
replace var1 = "A" if random1<.2
replace var1 = "B" if random1>=.2 & random1<.5
etc....
```

Note that sticking with the (scaled) probabilities after creating `var1` is desirable, but is not required for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that works in long form to select from the distribution. As values are selected, they are flagged as done and the next selection is made from the groups that contain the remaining values. Probabilities are scaled at each pass.

```
version 14
set seed 3241234

* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte ip str1 y double p
1 "A"  .2
2 "B"  .3
3 "C"  .1
4 "D" .15
5 "E" .25
end

local nval = _N

* the following should be true
isid y

expand 1000
bysort y: gen id = _n
sort id ip

gen done = 0

forvalues i = 1/`nval' {

    // scale probabilities
    bysort id done (ip): gen double ptot = sum(p)   // this is a running sum
    by id done: gen double phigh = sum(p / ptot[_N])
    by id done: gen double plow = cond(_n == 1, 0, phigh[_n-1])

    // random number in the range of (0,1) for the group
    bysort id done (ip): gen double x = runiform()

    // pick from the not done group; choose first x to represent group
    by id done: gen pick = !done & inrange(x[1], plow, phigh)

    // put the picked obs at the end and create the new var
    bysort id (pick ip): gen v`i' = y[_N]

    // we are done for the obs that was picked
    bysort id: replace done = 1 if _n == _N

    drop x pick ptot phigh plow
}

bysort id: keep if _n == 1
```

Comment: Works great! Could you just explain why we need to use `bysort id done (ip)` in the line: `bysort id done (ip): gen double x = runiform()`?

Comment: Actually, there's no reason to include the `bysort id done (ip)` part. Since the data is already sorted that way, the values of `x` will be the same, with and without. My bad, a leftover of playing around with the code to get it to work.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the answer and this follow-up explanation.